# Switch from textfield to displayfield with ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, textfield

I have created a form that displays values in plain displayfields.

There is an "edit" button next to the form and once clicked by the user, the displayfields should switch to being textfields and will, therefore, make the data editable.

This, I am guessing, would be achieved by having two identical forms, one editable and one not and one or the other would be visible, based on the user having clicked the button. Another way, perhaps, is to have the xtype dynamically selected upon clicking the button.

Can anybody point me towards a certain direction in order to do this? I am a complete newbie to ExtJS and only just started learning ExtJS4.

Thank you in advance.

M.

Comment: Switching the visibility is a very good approach. Switching the xtypes will not work, they are only used for initialization.

Comment: how about disabling the fields, and then enabling them in edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by rendering all fields as input fields with disabled:true. Then use this for the Edit button handler:

```
 ...
 form.getForm().getFields().each(function(field) {
             field.setDisabled( false); //use this to enable/disable 
             // field.setVisible( true); use this to show/hide
 }, form );//to use form in scope if needed
```

Comment: This should work beautifully!  I don't have time to try it out today, but will do tomorrow and will report back. Thank you!

Comment: It works as intended, but styling-wise, it doesn't look as I need it to. Ideally, I want it to switch from a textfield to an input field.
Regardless, this is a step towards the right direction, so thanks again.

Comment: The real alternative here is to have 2 Panels in a Card layout (meaning only one shown at a time). One panel is a form panel containing input fields for editing, while the other is a plain panel with xtemplate to render your data in a read-only mode. You can come up with something more creative than just a plain xtemplate for this, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.getCmp('yourfieldid').setFieldStyle('{color:black; border:0; background-color:yourcolor; background-image:none; padding-left:0}');
Ext.getCmp('yourfieldid').setReadOnly(true);
```

Comment: This worked better for me than disabling the field. Since I wanted a toggle between the two states, I add a style class and removed and added that class based on 'focus' and 'blur'

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle based on a property isEditable. Then when you click the button you change the property and just remove and add the form. It makes it cleaner if you are switching back and forth.

```
Ext.define('E.view.profile.information.Form', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'form',

title: 'Form',
layout: 'fit',

initComponent: function () {
    this.items = this.buildItems();
    this.callParent();
},

buildItems: function () {
    return [this.buildInvestmentPhilosophy()];
},

buildInvestmentPhilosophy: function () {
    var field = {
        name: 'investmentPhilosophy',
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        editableType: 'textarea',
        grow: true,
        maxLength: 6000,
        value: '---',
        renderer: E.Format.textFormatter
    };
    this.toggleEditingForForm(field);
    return field;
},

toggleEditingForForm: function (form) {
    if (this.isEditable) {
        Ext.Array.each(form, this.configureFieldForEditing, this);
    }
},

configureFieldForEditing: function (field) {
    if (field.editableType) {
        field.xtype = field.editableType;
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to have two items : a displayfield and a textfield with the same data source and you could hide/show the right item with your button handler.
You should not have any CSS problems

(If you did not have CSS problems I would enjoy to see you code)